# Good SQL practice for listing data for choosing

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, jdbc

I'm implementing a small database for my college course. There are (of course) operations to execute on some records in the DB, of which there are many and an user can't possibly know/remember all of them.

As an example, I have an operation "Find incidents relative to a plate number". I implemented it in JDBC in this way:

Execute a query that lists all of the plates numbers in the DB (Select * from Plates#)
Print all the results
Take as input from the user the chosen plate# 
Execute the query "Find incidents relative to a plate number" (Print an error if plate# is not found).

Now, I don't know if this is good practice though. My reasoning, again is that the user can't know in advance all the plates#, so I have to list them so he can choose one. And executing a query that lists them all is the only way I thought of doing this (because I can't access that data in any other way anyway).

So is this wrong or is there a "correct"/accepted way to tackle similar issues?

Comment: Is this a course assignment with the instruction ""Find incidents relative to a plate number?" I would interpret that to mean that the plate number is known and you have to find all of the related incidents.

Comment: It's not known. It's a generic query, the user can enter whatever they want as an input and might not know what's in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It would be wrong; in that particular situation (and in my opinion).

The number of "plates" could be in the millions, or perhaps just many thousands. The point is that the volume of that information is possibly overwhelming to the user if you attempt to present all of it, plus it is likely to cause major performance issues as well.

If there are only a few options, then present them to the user for choice. If there are many options then do not do that.

Instead of offering all plates up front, why not allow searching to narrow down the possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many possible plates there are you could:-

1. Count them `select count(*) from...` and implement paging, offering a reasonable number per page, with sort criteria.
2. Let the user home in on the plate number by first letter (the A's AB, ABG, AC, AH, AIB, etc.), then list them a page at a time. (That's assuming there is a scheme, like for German cities).
3. Use regular expressions if the user knows part of the licence number.